# Sort table by number of occurrence of one element

Tags: mysql

### Table

```
id Category Name
1  Sports   name1
2  Food     name2
3  Sports   name3
4  Social   name4
5  TV       name5
6  Food     name6
7  Sports   name7
8  TV       name8
```

How can I query * sorted by the most mention categories? the result should be something like:

```
Sports name1
Sports name3
Sports name7
Food name2
Food name6

and so.
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 0):

#### Number of times each category is mentioned

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS cat_count
  FROM anonymous_table
 GROUP BY category
```

#### Data sorted as requested

```
SELECT a.category, a.name
  FROM anonymous_table AS a
  JOIN (SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS cat_count
          FROM anonymous_table
         GROUP BY category
       ) AS c ON a.category = c.category
 ORDER BY c.cat_count DESC, a.name
```

---

> For some reason, it's not doing the job.

I tried the SQL above in Informix, and it 'worked', but gave an unexpected but explicable answer:

```
Sports    name1
Sports    name3
Sports    name7
Food      name2
TV        name5
Food      name6
TV        name8
Social    name4
```

There was nothing to keep the Food rows grouped together, and the sort on the names indeed forced them to be separated.  So, there needs to be an extra condition on the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT a.category, a.name
  FROM anonymous_table AS a
  JOIN (SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS cat_count
          FROM anonymous_table
         GROUP BY category
       ) AS c ON a.category = c.category
 ORDER BY c.cat_count DESC, a.category, a.name;
```

This gives a reasonable result:

```
Sports    name1     
Sports    name3     
Sports    name7     
Food      name2     
Food      name6     
TV        name5     
TV        name8     
Social    name4
```

If you want TV before food, you have to come up with some ordering scheme for that.  In the example, you could sort by category descending.  In the general case with quasi-arbitrary ordering of different categories, you'd add a category table and some ordering column (perhaps an ID, more likely separate from an ID column) that determines the relative ordering of different categories when other criteria are the same:

```
CREATE TABLE Category(Name CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Ordering INTEGER NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Category(Name, Ordering) VALUES('Sports', 10);
INSERT INTO Category(Name, Ordering) VALUES('TV',     20);
INSERT INTO Category(Name, Ordering) VALUES('Food',   30);
INSERT INTO Category(Name, Ordering) VALUES('Social', 40);

SELECT a.category, a.name
  FROM anonymous_table AS a
  JOIN category        AS b ON a.category = b.name
  JOIN (SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS cat_count
          FROM anonymous_table
         GROUP BY category
       ) AS c ON a.category = c.category
 ORDER BY c.cat_count DESC, b.ordering, a.category, a.name;
```

You still need to order by the category to ensure correct grouping since there isn't a unique constraint on the Category.Name column (though you could add one and then you could drop the `a.category` term from the ORDER BY clause).